# Manage different css folder for one sxa site

Tags: sxa

I have a `sxa` site with two different type of pages. Both pages have different layouts. I want to have different css and js folder for each page. Any way of achieving this in sxa

Comment: You want different CSS per site or per page?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal I want different css per page

Answer (score 1):

In your sitecore go to rendering -

```
/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Generic Meta Rendering/HTMLSnippet
```

In this rendering look at Datasource Location, it should be like this -

```
query:$site/*[@@name='Settings']/*[@@templatename='HTML Snippet Folder']|query:$sharedSites/*[@@name='Settings']/*[@@templatename='HTML Snippet Folder']
```

That means under your `site/settings` either you have a folder created by template or you can create an item using a template - `HTML Snippet Folder`, inside this template, create **Html Snippet** items. In these snippets, you can write your own CSS/JS or you can give reference to any CSS/JS in **HTML Snippet** field.

[image]

Now create a partial page design under `site/presentation/partial designs` and add `HTMLSnippet` rendering as a presentation and give Datasource of Html Snippet you have created. Now add this partial design to your required page design.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a `Page Design` and choosing a different theme for that `Page Design`, then you can select the new `Page Design` for your page, or associate your page template with that new `Page Design`:

[image]

Steps:

- Create a new Theme for your CSS
- Add that theme to the Compatible Themes in your Site Settings
- Create a new `Page Design`, set the theme to your new theme
- Associate your Page Template with your new `Page Design`

You can even use the original theme as the Base theme for your new theme to save restyling everything, and then just customize the new theme from there.